# ASP.NET streamfile damaged

Tags: c#, asp.net

Some files are downloaded outside of my site folder.
I created a CFilestream class that allows me to download large files.

When downloading files,the download is done correctly, but when opening a WORD file, a message indicates that the file is corrupted.

I can not find any solutions.

Please, could you help me ?
Thanks

```
public class CFilestream : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public void WriteFileToResponse(string strSecureFilePath, string strUserFilename, string strContentType = @"application/octet-stream")
    {
        byte[] dataBlock = new byte[0x1000];
        long fileSize;
        int bytesRead;
        long totalBytesRead = 0;

        try
        {

            using (var fs = new FileStream(strSecureFilePath,
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                fileSize = fs.Length;
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();

                Response.ContentType = strContentType;
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strUserFilename.Replace(" ", "_"));
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileSize.ToString());
                bool bContinue = true;
                while (totalBytesRead < fileSize && bContinue)
                {
                    if (!Response.IsClientConnected)
                    {
                        bContinue = false;
                    }

                    bytesRead = fs.Read(dataBlock, 0, dataBlock.Length);
                    Response.OutputStream.Write(dataBlock, 0, bytesRead);
                    Response.Flush();
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                }

                //Response.Close(); si activé problème dans chrome, téléchargement ne se termine pas
                //Response.End();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried running your program and it works correctly even for very large files (6 GB), so problem might be somewhere else - eiher in part of code you didn't provide or hardware malfunction or (anti)virus problem etc. Does this problem occur for all downloaded files, or just for this one particular word file?

Comment: Thanks for your testing.
The problem occurs with all Word files.
If I download them from a direct link the problem does not occur.

Comment: Did you check, if length of original Word file and downloaded file are the same (for example client might disconnect prematurely during download due to network problem). Also I would suggest to start with some very small file and use some hexadecimal comparison tool (I use Total Commander for that) to investigate differences between these file (are files completly different, or is there just a few bytes different, or is some part of file completelty missing?), which might give you a clue about the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your proposals. I will expect that

Comment: *no expect but try

Comment: I tried on small files and the size is different.A binary comparison also indicates that the files are different

Comment: Assuming corrupted file is shorter than original file, you can check if condition `!Response.IsClientConnected` becomes `true` during download - that would indicate that client disconnects prematurely. You can also try to download file directly on your server to rule out possibility of network problem.